Why a Python based Windows service can't be started
I want to develop a windows service using Python. As a try, I copied code from this page. Then I compiled it to exe with pyinstaller. Then I use wix make a msi and it as Windows 11 service.
But after installed, my service in SCM window is always STOPPED and can't be started. I don't know why.

My wix is just normal, add ServiceInstall element. I don't if wix matters.
The whole process reports no error.
More information: I just checked the event viewer. I got error in it. It reads like: waiting for service MyServiceTest connection timeout (30000 ms)
But I didn't understand the error message yet.
I found the fix here finally.

So there was really no error in event log?

@Sami, Yes I just checked the event viewer. I got error in it. It reads like: waiting for service MyServiceTest connection timeout (30000 ms)
